# How do you deserialize to a Kotlin Map from json?

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to deserialize to a `kotlin.collections.Map` from Json using Ktor and I continue to get an error, basically telling me it doesn't know how. I assumed this case was basic.

```kotlin
val beans = beans {
    bean("oauthClient") {

        HttpClient(CIO) {
            expectSuccess = true
            install(DefaultRequest){
                url("${env["oauth.url"]!!}/ms_oauth/oauth2/endpoints/oauthservice/tokens")
            }
            install(Auth) {
                basic {
                    credentials {
                        BasicAuthCredentials(username = env["client.id"]!!, password = env["client.secret"]!!)
                    }
                }
            }
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json()
            }
        }
    }
    bean {

        val oauthResults: Map<String,Any> = runBlocking { // blows up here
            ref<HttpClient>("oauthClient").submitForm("${env["oauth.url"]!!}/ms_oauth/oauth2/endpoints/oauthservice/tokens",
                Parameters.build {
                    append("grant_type", "password")
                    append("scope", "bug.rest.public")
                    append("username", env["ssoUsername"]!!)
                    append("password", env["ssoPassword"]!!)
                }
            ).body()
        }
    }
  }
```

error:

```
Caused by: io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: 
No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel -> class kotlin.collections.Map
```

Do I have to explicitly enable something? Or am I making a different mistake?

**Update**

I've since tried to marshal it into a data object and I get the same error, but referencing that object:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Oauth constructor(
    @SerialName("expires_in")
    val expiration: Int,
    @SerialName("token_type")
    val tokenType:String,
    @SerialName("access_token")
    val accessToken: String
)
```

error:

```
io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: 
No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel -> class com.company.Oauth
```

Comment: Not sure why it fails on `Map`, but I'm almost certain it's expected to fail on `Any`. How would you expect the library to deserialize things to `Any`? What should be the actual runtime type of the values? You could use `JsonElement` as value instead, though, to check if it solves your map problem

Comment: I've also tried it as `Map<String,String>` to the same effect. The problem is that the values are mixed types. When I was using jackson with RestTemplate, it handle this case just fine.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're using the `HttpClient` with JSON content negotiation setup that we see defined in the code here? Because it really looks like Ktor doesn't find the relevant converter. Maybe the content type of the response is not `application/json`?

Answer (score 1):

Alongside

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
```

you also need [explicit dependencies](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html#add_dependencies) to

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.1")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.1")
```

and an [HTTP client configuration](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html#register_json) to let *Ktor* know how to deserialize the data, for example

```kotlin
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.java.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.net.http.HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2

val httpClient = HttpClient(Java) {
    engine {
        threadsCount = 4
        pipelining = true
        protocolVersion = HTTP_2
    }

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })
    }
}
```

This way the *Ktor Client* will be able to actually use the *kotlinx.serialization* to deserialize the response into your desired entity `Oauth`.

Alternatively, if you really want only a simple `Map` object instead of complex (de)serialization then I'm pretty sure you'd need to use either *Gson*, *Jackson*, *Moshi* or something as simple as *[Klaxon](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon)* to deserialize the response body string.

For example, using *Klaxon*:

```kotlin
val parser: Parser = Parser.default()
val body: String = httpClient.get("https://example.com/api/tokens").bodyAsText()
val json: JsonObject = parser.parse(body) as JsonObject
```

where `JsonObject` behaves almost like a `Map`: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon#low-level-api